# Regardless of Windows language, how can I make the ICACLS command set a folder to have full access to everyone?

Tags: windows, permissions, file-permissions, language, icacls

**Background**

Say I have this command

`icacls C:\FullyAccessibleFolder /grant Users:(OI)(CI)F`

This works fine in English versions of Windows, but does not seem to work in French versions, giving the following error, presumably due to `Users` being different in French. `Everyone` gets translated as `Tout le monde` in Windows, so that's not a solution either.

`Users: Le mappage entre les noms de compte et les ID de sécurité n'a pas été effectué.`

Which Google translates as

`Users: The mapping between account names and security IDs was not performed.`

**Question**

Is there a command I can use to set a folder and recursively all of its contents to have full permissions for all users in a way that would work across different language versions of Windows?

**Content from around the web**

[This page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21324368) with a largely similar problem talks about how `Everyone` becomes `Jeder` in German and `Tout le monde` in French.

Comment: Just use the SID: `icacls C:\FullyAccessibleFolder /grant S-1-5-32-545:(OI)(CI)F`  Works everywhere.

Comment: @Ben, that should be `icacls C:\folder /grant *S-1-5-32-545:(OI)(CI)F`, you left out the asterisk.

Comment: The solutions in these answers are helpful.  But elsewhere @Eryk Sun shared a nice tip that instead of these numeric Trustee SIDs, you can use language-independent Trustee alias human-readable strings with icacls instead of the numeric Trustee SID.  For example, BU = Builtin\Users (English language install).  The alias still needs to begin with an *: `icacls C:\folder /grant *BU:(OI)(CI)F`
See the Trustee section in https://web.archive.org/web/20231205112258/https://itconnect.uw.edu/tools-services-support/it-systems-infrastructure/msinf/other-help/understanding-sddl-syntax/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Does not work in French versions, presumably due to `Users` being different

You have three options, detailed below:

1. Use the Use the [Language Portal](https://www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Search.aspx) to get the translated name
2. Retrieve the localised name from the `Users` SID
3. Use the `Users` SID with `icacls`

---

#### Option 1: Use the [Language Portal](https://www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Search.aspx) (canonical resource for Microsoft Terminology)

A search for [Users](https://www.microsoft.com/language/en-us/Search.aspx?sString=users&langID=fr-fr) returns:

> **Translations in Localized Microsoft Products**

```
    English Translation         Product
    Users   Utilisateurs        Windows 7
    Users   des utilisateurs    Windows 7
    Users   Utilisateurs        Windows 8 Modern Voice
    Users   Utilisateurs        Windows 8
    Users   Utilisateurs        Windows 8.1
    USERS   UTILISATEURS        Windows 8.1
    Users   Utilisateurs        Windows 10
    Users   des utilisateurs    Windows 10
    Users   Utilisateurs        Windows 10 Anniversary Update
    users   utilisateurs        Windows 10 Anniversary Update
```

This suggests the following command may work:

```
icacls C:\FullyAccessibleFolder /grant Utilisateurs:(OI)(CI)F
```

---

#### Option 2: Retrieve the localised name from the `Users` SID (`S-1-5-32-545`)

> SID: S-1-5-32-545
>
> Name: Users
>
> Description: A built-in group. After the
>   initial installation of the operating system, the only member is the
>   Authenticated Users group. When a computer joins a domain, the Domain
>   Users group is added to the Users group on the computer.

Source [Well-known security identifiers in Windows operating systems](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/243330/well-known-security-identifiers-in-windows-operating-systems)

To retrieve the localised `Users` group name:

> This simple script
>   will give you actual name of 'Users' `(S-1-5-32-545)` group on a given
>   PC:
>
> ```
>     Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
>     Set objAccount = objWMIService.Get ("Win32_SID.SID='S-1-5-32-545'")
>     Wscript.Echo objAccount.AccountName
> ```
>
> Put it into a file with vbs extension (Let's assume
>   `usersName.vbs`).
>
> Now run:
>
> ```
> echo Y|for /f "delims=" %i in ('cscript -Nologo usersName.vbs') do cacls foldername /G "%i":F
> ```

Source [Cacls, Windows 7, full permissions, local names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113206/cacls-windows-7-full-permissions-local-names) by [wmz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1123692/wmz)

---

#### Option 3: Use the `Users` SID with `icacls`

Use the following command:

```
icacls C:\FullyAccessibleFolder /grant *S-1-5-32-545:(OI)(CI)F
```

Source comment by [Harry Johnston](https://superuser.com/users/96662/harry-johnston)

Comment: I've accepted the answer from DavidPostill as it does it in a true command line way, which is great when using batch or PS scripts. In the end I actually created a little executable in C# which just takes a path and does exactly what I need to. It's not as customisable as the answers here, and it requires .NET Framework, but it does suit my particular purpose very well. If anyone is interested, here is the the basis of the C# code I ended up going with. http://stackoverflow.com/a/35461832/1639615

Comment: `xcacls` appears to be a script you can download.  There's no need; `icacls` is built into Windows and can do the same job.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Correct, but my answer is showing how to retrieve the localised version of `Users` ... I've clarified the answer as we don't need the `xacls` part of the quoted solution.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I've also added using `icacls` directly with credit to you.

Answer (score 7):

You need to specify the AD-group not by its name, but by the SID number.
For standard groups like "EveryOne", "Domain Users", etc. there are standardized SID numbers, which can be found on the MSDN page [Well-known security identifiers (SIDs)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379649(v=vs.85).aspx).

The following are the most common relative identifiers.

[image]

The structure of a SID is describe as the following:

> The components of a SID are easier to visualize when SIDs are
>   converted from binary to string format by using standard notation:
>
> S-R-X-Y1-Y2-Yn-1-Yn
>
> ```
>     Component                   Definition
>
>     S                         Indicates that the string is a SID
>     R                         Revision level
>     X                         Identifier authority value
>     Y            A series of subauthority values, where n is the number of values
> ```
>
> For example, the SID for the built-in Administrators group is
>   represented in standardized SID notation as the following string:
>
> S-1-5-32-544
>
> This SID has four components:
>
> - A revision level (1)
> - An identifier authority value (5, NT Authority)
> - A domain identifier (32, Builtin)
> - A relative identifier (544, Administrators)

[How Security Identifiers Work](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778824(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: It is worth pointing out that all users are part of the User group by default.  So if you want to give "full access:to all user accounts, just use SID `S-1-5-32-544`, and then modify the ACL to give all permissions to the group for the file or folder in question

Comment: @Ramhound `544` is Administrators, `545` is Users.

Comment: @DavidPostill - Yes; Copy and paste error.

Comment: @Ramhound Much better. It was the best I could do while being on a phone. Thank for the edit.

Answer (score 4):

If you like PowerShell scripts but have trouble remembering numbers for SIDs:

```
$acl = Get-Acl .\myfolder
$sid = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier ([System.Security.Principal.WellKnownSidType]::BuiltinUsersSid, $null)
$rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule ($sid, 'FullControl', 'ObjectInherit,ContainerInherit', 'None', 'Allow')
$acl.AddAccessRule($rule)
Set-Acl .\myfolder $acl
```

I know that looks like a ton of typing, but these long identifiers are tab-completed:

- `System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier` from `securityi`
- `System.Security.Principal.WellKnownSidType` from `wellknownsi`
- `System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule` from `filesystem`

All these strings are .NET identifiers, so they don't get localized.

If you want the `Everyone` SID instead, use `WorldSid` in place of `BuiltinUsersSid`. To get the list of all `WellKnownSidType` options, [see MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.wellknownsidtype(v=vs.110).aspx) or run this command:

```
[System.Security.Principal.WellKnownSidType].DeclaredFields | select Name
```

Comment: _FileSystemAccessRule_ without ***Sid*** and using `group names` ?

Comment: @Kiquenet I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but if you prefer to specify a human-readable group name, that will no longer be language-independent. If you're OK with that, you can remove the `$sid =` line and replace `$sid` in the `$rule =` line with a string identifying the group.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to achieve in Powershell. I can confirm that this works independent of the system language and is unaffected by the localized name for `BUILTIN\Users` (`VORDEFINIERT\Users` on German systems for example).

Answer (score 0):

Based on DavidPostill's Option 2, here's a batch which will give local language SID name, the advantage is that CACLS may be used instead (can't set ReadOnly with ICACLS):

```
  rem https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/manage/understand-security-identifiers
set userSID=S-1-1-0& rem EVERYBODY
  rem generate temp sid2user.VBS script to get local language userSID name
( echo\Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2"^)
  echo\Wscript.Echo objWMIService.Get("Win32_SID.SID='%userSID%'" ^).AccountName
) > "%TEMP%\sid2user.vbs"
  rem set lang_user to userSID local language name
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('cscript -Nologo "%TEMP%\sid2user.vbs"') do set lang_user=%%i
  rem remove temp vbs file
del "%TEMP%\sid2user.vbs"
echo "%lang_user%"
  rem set permissions with icacls
cacls C:\FullyAccessibleFolder /t /l /c /g "%lang_user%":F
```